# Using jAlert as a simple Prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, prompt

I'm using with satisfaction the library jAlert v4 available [here](http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/)

But I noticed that is not possible to use this library such as a simple "prompt" (that is a simple alert with a textbox) as shown in the following code:

```
 var qnt = prompt("Insert")
```

Also this library is excellent because it automatically recognize all "alert()" functions in my code and applies his styles without any further implementation (it needs only to add its libraries inside `<head>` tag). 
I discovered that there is also the "jQuery Alert Dialogs" library for my purpose, but it isn't customizable as jAlert v4.

So I would like to know if is possible to use the same library (jAlert v4) for my purpose, because I like the jalert customization (for ex. themes and animations) and it is very easy to use.
And I want to keep the same style like my jAlert as picture below: [jAlert example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTK2o.jpg)  but with a input TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library is overriding the browser's built-in `alert()` function.  You can do the same with `prompt()`, and have it open a jAlert with a text box on it.

```
window.prompt = function(title, value){
    $.jAlert({
        # Add an input field
        'content': '<form><label>'+title+'</label><input value="'+(value||'')+'"></form>'
        # Add the buttons or whatever else you need to the jAlert
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but but I found another solution always using the library jalert that you can find in my aswer.

Answer (score 1):

The browser dialog stuff, such as `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt` are all blocking.  JavaScript execute stops as those run.

There is simply no way to reproduce that behavior in external code, which means that one has to resort to using callbacks.

For some things, such as `alert` it may not be an issue .. if the code continues while the alert is still displayed, but it will fall apart if you try to show several alerts in a row.

For `prompt` and `confirm`, however, you *will* have to restructure your code.

*I did a quick read of the `jAlert` docs and I saw both `alert` and `confirm` -- they didn't seem to have a `prompt` replacement, so I couldn't show their demo code*

It might be worth checking out this library instead:
http://alertifyjs.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but but I found another solution always using the library jalert that you can find in my aswer.

Comment: I'm the developer of jAlert and I didn't include prompt because it generally needs to be very custom. I create jAlerts for prompting all the time, but I do them long-hand because I want full control. Also, there is an example on the codepen for "adding products" here: http://codepen.io/VersatilityWerks/pen/yNXLNB/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If you just put the input box into the content, that will not appears, it's true. This is why you have the `onOpen` callback:

```
 $.alertOnClick('.getTopClose', {
    'title':'Textbox example',
    'content':'', //Add nothing to the content
    'onOpen': function(alert){
       //This is the important part!
       //Append a text input to the class .ja_body
       $('.ja_body').append('<input type="text" name="something" value="" />'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but but I found another solution always using the library jalert that you can find in my aswer.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for my issue. And It's simply because always using the same jalert library. In my cause I use the returned value of my alert to perform an UPDATE via ajax. This is my code:

```
    $.jAlert({
    'title': 'Inserimento numero colli',
    'content': '<form style="text-align:center;"><label>Quantita</label><br><input id="id_qnt" type="text" style="text-align:center"></form>',
    'btns': [
        {
            'text': 'Save',
            'closeAlert': 'false',
            'onClick': function (e, btn) {
                var item = btn.parents('.jAlert'),
                    form = item.find('form'),
                    error = false;
                var field = form.find('input:text').val();
                if (field == 'undefined' || field == '') {
                    error = "Empty quantity!";
                }
                if (!($.isNumeric(field))) {
                    error = "IsNan!"
                }
                if (field < 0) {
                    error = "IT'S < 0"
                }
                if (error) {
                    errorAlert(error);
                    return false;
                }

                // 'field' is the returned value... such as when using 'prompt'
                // In my case I use it for AJAX 

                var obj = {};
                obj.value = field;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Master.aspx/UpdateItem",
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        successAlert('SUCCESSFULLY SENT!', r.d);
                    }
                });

                // DYNAMICALLY CHANGE VALUE INSIDE PAGE change clicked_id by passing your id 
                document.getElementById(clicked_id).textContent = obj.value;
            }
        },
        {
            'text': 'Cancel'
        }
    ]
});
```

It looks like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXIWU.jpg)
I hope will be helpful to everyone!